# Solving the Matrix for E, given EB = A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
And B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 6 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

So the equation EB = A eventually turns into E = AB^-1.

(not sure if I'm supposed to show my steps, but the inverted B matrix I got was:
\begin{bmatrix}
7/9 & 1/9 & 1/9 \\
-2/9 & 1/9 & 1/9 \\
-5/9 & 7/9 & -2/9
\end{bmatrix}
this might be where my errors came in, but let me know what you guys think or if I should show my steps.

Then, I got this for AB^-1.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 42/9 & -2/3 \\
0 & -12/9 & 1/3 \\
0 & -21/9 & 13/9
\end{bmatrix}

It said this was wrong, so any help is welcome. Again, this is only my second post and the last one was not the best haha. Please let me know how I can improve at all. Thanks!

Comment: Try to check if $BB^{-1}=B^{-1}B=I$ to verify if $B^{-1}$ is calculated properly.

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure. I got the \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got $B^{-1}$ correct.  The error is in calculating $A B^{-1}$, the resulting matrix should be

$ E = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

But, actually, you don't need to calculate $B^{-1}$ here.  If you look closely at $A$ and $B$, you'll see that $B$ is matrix $A$ with rows $(1)$ and $(3)$ flipped, so matrix $E$ must be the matrix above.

Comment: oh my gosh, I don't know how I didn't see that. Not exactly sure how to get that same E, I'll try doing my calculations again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure.  My pleasure.